# Splitting a 2D array size to a smaller 2D Array size in C

Tags: arrays, c

Disclaimer: I'm not very good with words, I have included a sample of how will it look like below.

So I'm trying to reduce this 4x4 array into a bunch of 2x2 arrays. (See sample below)

```
 int disp[4][4] = {{12,4,32,9}, {19,24,3,4},{1,26,3,8},{3,24,7,5} };
/*
 
12 4 32 9                            12 4 | 32 9
19 24 3 4    into something like    19 24 | 3  4
1 26 3 8                            =============
3 24 7 5                            1 26  | 3 8
                                    3 24  | 7 5
*/
```

Take note: it is splitting it into smaller sizes (bunch of 2D arrays)
I have tried splitting it using a for loop code but only getting the 2nd quadrant.

code below:

```
int i,j;
for(i=0;i<2;i++)
for(j=0;j<2;j++)
printf("%d\n",disp[i][j]);
```

see that this only gives me 12,4,19 and 24.
Is there a way to get the other quadrants? How would this work for bigger sizes? (Lets say 28x28 to 14x14) I would really appreciate the help. Thank you.

Comment: Use basic maths and logic to reason it out. For example, for the top right quadrant what does the start row need to be? That's the initial `j` value. What does the start column need to be? That's the starting `i` value. And so on. Do that with four seperate nested loops, one for each quadrant, if that helps. Then once that works you can go back to improve it by factoring the code.

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider a **NXN matrix** where N and **quadrant_size** be the required size of sub_matrix to be printed.

We first traverse to find the starting element to be printed in each sub_matrix.

i.e: From 0 to N incrementing by quadrant_size for row and 0 to N incrementing by quadrant_size for column.(First two loops in the below given code)

Let's say (x,y) index at any position. Now we print the matrix elements from (x,y) to (x+2,y+2)

The below code is generalized for any size of **matrix NxN** of required **quadrant_size** where N should be divisible by quadrant_size.

```
int quadrant_size=2;
//outer loop to traverse the starting elements of the sub array
for(int x=0 ; x<N ; x+=quadrant_size){
   for(int y=0 ; y<N ; y+=quadrant_size){
        //inner loop to print matrix  
        for(int i=x ; i<x+quadrant_size ; i++){
            for(int j=y ; j<y+quadrant_size ; j++){
                printf("%d ",disp[i][j]); 
            } 
            printf("\n"); 
        } 
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you upgrade to a program which demonstrates the effect of your code? E.g. by using recognisable values. You may want to first ask OP for a [mre] as a foundation. In spite of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead you can do so as a comment on your own post.

Comment: You don't need 4 loops... 3 loops should do

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an offset to `i` and `j` depending on which quadrant you want to print.

For your specific case it could be:

```
int main() {
    int disp[4][4] = {{12,4,32,9}, 
                      {19,24,3,4},
                      {1,26,3,8},
                      {3,24,7,5} };

    // calculate quadrant size (it will be 2 in this case)
    int qsize = sizeof disp[0] /sizeof disp[0][0] / 2;
                      
    int q = 3;   // <--- The quadrant to print

    int offset_i = 0;  // Extra offsets for
    int offset_j = 0;  // the loop that prints
    if (q == 1)
    {
        offset_j = qsize;
    }
    else if (q == 3)
    {
        offset_i = qsize;
    }
    else if (q == 4)
    {
        offset_i = qsize;
        offset_j = qsize;
    }
                          
    for(int i=0; i<qsize; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<qsize; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ",disp[i + offset_i][j + offset_j]);
                     // Notice: ^^^^^^^^^^    ^^^^^^^^^^
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```